# How to set the last item in a scrollview properly in ios

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

- Assuming I have a `scrollview` in the view controller attached to the View:
  [image]
  With constraints (top:0, bottom:0, leading:0, trailing:0) set to its super view

---

- I then add a `contentview` into the `scrollview`:
  [image]
  Where it has (top:0, bottom:0, leading:0, trailing:0, equal width:priority=250)) aligments set to the `scrollview`

---

- I now begin to add items into the `contentview`:

  - start with a few fixed-size items and added them vertically and have each of their top constraints set to the item above them.
  - add another label with (top/leading/trailing) constraints setup but leave its bottom free since I want its height to adapt to dynamic input length.
  - **Here comes the final item, a button**. I want it to have 30 top spacing with the dynamic text label, and 40 bottom spacing to the page end. However, everything goes wrong with red warnings, the `scrollview` starts getting confused with its height:

  [image]

### [image]

I got a lot of red constraints errors as you can see:

[image]

And it gets messier if I change the font size of the dynamic-height label which results in more errors since the height and constraints are no longer matched.

---

So what is the best way to deal with the last item properly under such a circumstance which might happen in daily development?

Answer (score 0):

Try below anyone constraints, i guess problem will resolve:

1. set height constraints for ContentView as greater than scrollView
2. set height constraints for scrollview and give less priority e.g. 500, 750 etc.

Comment: Yes! indeed, no warnings any more. But why would this work? and will my content height become a fixed instead of dynamic value?